# AssertionError: expected 0 to equal " ". The numerical values of the inputs were compared, and they differed

Tags: solidity, hardhat, testing, chai

I'm pretty new to coding and solidiy - I'm testing a covered-call option smart contract in hardhat - specifically a function to check if the balance of the smart contract has been updated following the collateral being deposited by the call writer.

here is my smart contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract CoveredCallContract {

    address public callWriter;
    address public callBuyer;
    uint public amount;
    uint public optionPrice;
    uint public strikePrice;
    uint public expiryDate;
    bool wasPurchased;

    constructor(uint _amount, uint _optionPrice, uint _strikePrice) {
        callWriter = msg.sender;
        amount = _amount;
        optionPrice = _optionPrice;
        strikePrice = _strikePrice;
        expiryDate = block.timestamp + 1 weeks;
    }

    // this function is how the callwriter deposits the collateral to cover the option
    function depositCollateral() public payable {
        require(msg.value >= amount, " Insufficient balance");
    }

    // this function allows the buyer to purchase the contract and pay the premium
    function purchaseOption() external payable {
        // ensure buyer hasn't already bought the option
        require(wasPurchased == false);
        // ensure buyer sends the correct amount
        require(msg.value == optionPrice, "Incorrect purchase price");
        // set the option buyer to the callbuyer
        callBuyer = msg.sender;
        // if the buyer buys the option, the price is transfered directly to the writer
        payable(callWriter).transfer(msg.value);
        // set the wasPurchased to true one the option has been purchased
        wasPurchased = true;

    }

    // the option will be executed if the price of ETH is above the strike price 
    function executeOption() external payable {
        // ensure the buyer has purchased the option
        require(wasPurchased == true);
        // make sure it's the buyer executing the contract
        require(msg.sender == callBuyer, "Unauthorized");
        // ensure the contract has been funded by the call writer
        require(address(this).balance == amount, "Funding error");
        // ensure the amount the buyer pays at execution is equal to the strikeprice
        require(msg.value == strikePrice, "Payment error");
        // make sure the contract has not expired
        require(block.timestamp < expiryDate, "Option has already expired");
        // if all the above hold transfer the amount to the buyer
        payable(callBuyer).transfer(address(this).balance);
    }

    // if the option is not executed the initial funds will be sent back to the call writer
    function refund() public payable {
        if(wasPurchased == false) {
            require(block.timestamp >= expiryDate, "Option has not expired yet");    
        }
        payable(callWriter).transfer((address(this).balance));
    }
}
```

and here is my JS test:

```
describe("CoveredCallContract", function () {

  let coveredCallContract;
  let callWriter;
  let callBuyer;
  const amount = ethers.utils.parseEther("1");
  const optionPrice = ethers.utils.parseEther("0.1");
  const strikePrice = ethers.utils.parseEther("1.5");

  this.beforeEach(async () => {
    [callWriter, callBuyer] = await ethers.getSigners();
    const CoveredCallContract = await ethers.getContractFactory("CoveredCallContract");
    coveredCallContract = await CoveredCallContract.deploy(amount, optionPrice, strikePrice);
    await coveredCallContract.deployed();
  });

  it("should have call writer address equal the deployer address", async () => {
    assert(await coveredCallContract.connect(callWriter))
  })

  it('should set option expiry date', async () => {
    const expiryDate = await coveredCallContract.expiryDate();
    assert(expiryDate);
  });

  it('should not have an intial ether balnce in the contract', async () => {
    const balance = await ethers.provider.getBalance(coveredCallContract.address);
    assert.equal(balance, 0);
    console.log(balance);
  });

  it('should NOT deposit collateral if writers balance is too low', async () => {
    const writerBalance = await ethers.provider.getBalance(callWriter.address);
    expect(writerBalance).to.be.greaterThan(amount);
  });
    
  it('should deposit the collateral', async () => {
    await coveredCallContract.connect(callWriter).depositCollateral({value: amount});
  });

  it('should now have an ether balance', async () => {
    const balance = await ethers.provider.getBalance(coveredCallContract.address);
    await expect(balance).to.be.equal(amount);
    console.log(balance);
  });  

  it('should NOT buy option if not paying the correct price', async () => {
    await expect(coveredCallContract.purchaseOption({value: ethers.utils.parseEther("0.2")})).to.be.revertedWith("Incorrect purchase price");
  });

  it('should purchase option', async () => {
    await coveredCallContract.purchaseOption({value: optionPrice});
  });

  it('should execute option', async () => {
    await coveredCallContract.connect(callBuyer).executeOption({value: strikePrice});
  });

  it('should refund the writer if option not executed', async () => {
    const expiryDate = await coveredCallContract.expiryDate();
    const unixSeconds = Math.round(Date.now() / 1000);
    const oneWeek = 7 * 24 * 60 * 60;
    assert.isAtLeast(expiryDate, await hre.network.provider.request({
      method: "evm_setNextBlockTimestamp",
      params: [unixSeconds + oneWeek]
    }));
    await hre.network.provider.request({ method: "evm_mine" });
    await coveredCallContract.refund({value: amount});
  });
})
```

My previous test to deposit the collateral amount into the smart contract passed so I was expecting that the smart contract should now have a balance equal to that of rhe collateral amount but it keeps failing with an assertion Error.

I think this is also causing the test to execute the option to fail as well but I'm not sure.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

thanks

Comment: Are you using a local or test network for the deployment?

Comment: test network - goerli specifically